# Find platform-specific null devices in PHP?

Tags: php, null, multiplatform

Is there something like Python's `os.path.devnull` that points to the right null device for given platform in `PHP` (preferably `v5.6`)?

I see nothing obvious in the manual, `phpinfo()`, `$_SERVER` or `$_ENV` and googling mostly results in python references. I fail to believe there's no such thing. What am I missing?

Comment: There is no such thing

Comment: Depends on what you mean and how you plan to use it.  You just want to execute something and discard the return? What and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has no such thing built-in. However, reading the [Python](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/os.py) and [PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0d51ebd1a54af59d915c551a240b56bb3f0e26a6/configure.in#L1300) source reveals a very easy solution:

```
function devnull()
{
    $osToNull = [
        // Windows
        'WIN' => 'nul',

        // OS2, eComStation
        'OS2' => 'nul',

        // RISC OS
        'RISC' => 'null:',

        // AmigaOS
        'AMIGA' => 'nil:',

        // OpenVMS
        'VMS' => 'nl:',

        // Unix, Netware
        // returned if no other OS matches
        'default' => '/dev/null',
    ];

    foreach ($osToNull as $os => $nullDevice) {
        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, strlen($os))) === $os) {
            return $nullDevice;
        }
    }

    return $osToNull['default'];
}
```

As I do not have access to all above OSes, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It's shame to hear there's no built-in solution but since I only need this for now, marking as best answer. I added systems I needed.

Comment: @CyprianGuerra Would you mind sharing the systems and their null device location for completeness sake?

Comment: Yeah, I added an edit about 30 mins ago. It'll appear after approval. `'Amiga' => 'nil:', 'VMS' => 'nl:'`

Comment: @cprn Ah I never noticed, I updated the answer to include your comment.